# Change settings with macros TeXstudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, viewers, scripts

I'd like to have a macro in my TeXstudio to change settings, more specifically PdfLaTeX command from

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

to

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=0 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

And vice versa. This will prevent viewer from jumping to the latest changes. Especially it's annoying when I change something in the preamble and it jumps all the way to the top.

I'd be really nice to set a shortcut or put a button on the toolbar for switching the commands.

Comment: You don't need to do this to disable that behavior. Simply disable the feature below the pdf viewer window. There are two buttons with arrows: one is *cursor follows scrolling* and other is *scrolling follows cursor*. They are responsible for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found even more elegant way of switching between `synctex` option without macros.

You just need to go to `Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Build` and under the `Meta Commands` there is block with `User command` where you can add

```
txs:///compile/[-synctex=0] | txs:///view
```

which does exactly what a default `Build & View` button, but with `synctex` disabled.

[image]

After that you can find the custom command under `Tools -> User` or set a keyboard shortcut.